# Confirm purchase on second party site

Tags: e-commerce, google-checkout

I am selling tickets through Google check out.  The tickets are created automatically by my web site which also creates the Google checkout link, on the fly.  I want my database to be updated once someone completes their transaction.  I figured I could attach a link to the Google check out widget then once the transaction goes through, they are taken to that page and the page updates my database.  Unfortunately, I can see the link when I view the source of the pre transaction page.  So a user could just copy that link and go right to that page without completing a transaction.  My system would think they bought a ticket without them paying for it.  Is there a way to embed the link in the Google check out widget, that a user would not be able to see, or do I have to do this in a different way, with the more complicated Google checkout api's.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check php's  `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and see if it comes from google.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER can be manipulated by the user.  I figure if they are smart enough to copy the link from the source they would be smart enough to change that as well.  Maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

The Checkout Notification API is the recommend and the most secure option, if you're ok doing some programming on the server side:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html

You could experiment with the "continue_url" parameter and take the user back to your site after the transaction has completed, however, note that the user *has* to click on the continue_url link and there is no guarantee that the payment has been accepted:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_How_Checkout_Works.html#Cart_Input_Fields